# How to write the HQL query for database view in mysql

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I am using netbean and followed below steps to execute HQL query for table

1. Did Reverse Engg
2. Generated mapping and POJO

   ```
   Query query = session.createQuery("from MasUser as masUser where masUser.userName = '" + userName + "'");
   masUser = (masUser) query.uniqueResult();
   ```

Now I am able to execute and got result.

---

Then I have created view for this table

```
  CREATE VIEW test_view AS SELECT user_name, address FROM mas_user
```

Now I need to execute test_view in hibernate HQL.

Please provide the steps.

Comment: see this post :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901537/elegant-ways-to-handle-database-views-on-hibernate-entities

Comment: Sorry.. This link is not having answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created the view in the database, the process of querying a view is exactly the same as working with a table.  Simply create an entity (POJO) for the view, attach the mapping annotations and then create and execute a query.  Repeat the same process that you did for your MasUser table.