# grails create domain class for mysql view

Tags: grails

I have mysql view with combining multiple tables column. I want to only select data from this view to display web in html page. no need to create/update/delete using GORM. how can I define the domain class for this view?

my view is like this.

```
view name: testview
col1 int,
col2 varchat(50),
col3 date
```

thanks

Comment: What is the primary key?

Comment: Yes I understand this is a view, I meant to ask what is the "acting" primary key?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming col1 is the primary key:

```
class View {
    Integer col1
    String col2
    Date col3

    static mapping = {
        table name: "testview"
        version false
        id name: "col1", generator: "assigned"

        // These are unnecessary unless you change the name of the fields
        col1 column: "col1"
        col2 column: "col2"
        col3 column: "col3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grails gorm does not provide direct access to views, but you can try HQL, or refer to [Elegant ways to handle database views on hibernate entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901537/elegant-ways-to-handle-database-views-on-hibernate-entities).