# Convert query into a hibernate query and update new table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

So the problem statement is that I need to update my **tag_statistics** table. Fairly new to all these joins and such in Hibernate so I've tried to put in as much information as possible to help you solve the problem.

The easy workaround I have is to just use a rawQuery and update my MySQL backend quickly but I want to know how this would get done if it were to be done using Hibernate properly. I'm using Hibernate 4.2.2 (I don't mind upgrading further if necessary)

Thanks! Looking forward to your suggestions and solutions.

So here's the query that needs to be converted:

> SELECT t.id, SUM(ps.solved) as total_solved FROM `tags` as t,
>   `problem_tag_mapping` as ptm, `problems_solved` as ps where t.id =
>   ptm.tag_id and ptm.problem_id = ps.problem_id GROUP BY t.id";

I would then use the output of this to update **tag_statistics** table.

---

This is what the database looks like:

**tags**

> id(bigint),
>   name(varchar)

**problems**

> id(bigint),
>   code(varchar)

**problems_solved**

> problem_id (FK - bigint)
>   solved(int)

**problem_tag_mapping**

> problem_id (FK - bigint)
>   tag_id (FK - bigint)

**tag_statistics**

> tag_id (FK - bigint)
>   solved(int)

---

This is what the Hibernate entities look like (just the interesting stuff - feel free to ask for more code):

**ProblemsEntity**

> @ManyToMany
>   @JoinTable(name, joinColumns, inverseJoinColumns)
>   TagsEntity
>
> @OneToOne(mappedBy)
>   ProblemsSolvedEntity

**TagsEntity**

> @ManyToMany(mappedBy)
>   ProblemsEntity

**ProblemsSolvedEntity**

> @OneToOne
>   @JoinColumn
>   ProblemsEntity

Comment: tag_statistics looks like a view. Why do you use table not view?

Comment: Err.. ok yes you are indeed correct. I don't need a table. How would I make a view with hibernate given that raw MySQL query?

Comment: Maybe you will find useful hints under that URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255016/how-to-create-call-a-sql-view-in-hibernate